# Exclude Firebase Server dependecies in Android App with Firebase

Tags: java, android, google-app-engine, gradle, firebase

We have 3 modules:

1. app: Android app with Firebase DB, Auth, Storage dependecies
2. backend: Google App Engine server with Firebase Server dependencies
3. models: models for Firebase DB

Dependecies are managed with Gradle.

Both app and backend use the models module, which defines all Firebase DB models. Now we want to use Firebase Annotatations (@Exclude ...) in our models.

Is there any gradle dependency for Firebase Annotations only?

When I include the Firebase server dependecy in models and include models in the app, the app has problems with the transitive dependencies (Firebase Android <-> Firebase Server).

Is there any smart solutions from the Firebase Team?
I tried

```
{ transitive: false }
```

in Gradle but I did not work...